# CUDA 5 NSIGHT set compilation flag

Tags: cuda, nsight

In order to compile project for Kepler K20 we need to set `-rdc=true` flag. How can we set this flag in nsight eclipse edition? my version is CUDA 5.K20. nsight eclipse edition

Comment: You don't need `-rdc=true` for Kepler.  You do want `-arch=sm_35` (for K20) but Nsight EE can set that automatically for you via the project property pages.  `-rdc=true` is required for certain kinds of project structures (libraries, incremental compile, etc.) and in addition to `-rdc=true` at the link step you will want `-dc` instead of `-c` where ever you have a compile-to-object step.  Nsight EE has project types that can handle this for you automatically as well, depending on your type of project.

Comment: Compilation process threw error when I didn't mention `rdc=true` something like undefined reference to Buffer..

Comment: Yes, agreed, but it's because of the way your project is structured.  It's not a requirement of Kepler K20.

Comment: I have just one file..nothing fancy..still it shows error, program is compiling with command outside nsight EE but not in EE.

Comment: If you're still having trouble, perhaps you should post a simple, complete example code that shows the problem, along with the steps you went through to set up the Nsight EE project.  If your entire program is only a single file, the `-rdc` flag shouldn't be necessary.  You may not have chosen a convenient project type in Nsight EE.  You can probably also figure it out just by comparing the compile command line that Nsight EE is using to the one you are using manually that works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To enable separate compilation in Nsight Eclipse Edition:

1. Open project properties
2. In the left-hand tree, select "Build"/"CUDA"
3. Select "Separate Compilation" radio button at the top of the page.
4. Clean the project and rebuild.

This way Nsight will specify -rdc=true both to the compiler and linker.

Answer (score 1):

For additional options like `-rdc`, you could add them directly in the command line of the compiler settings.

In your Nsight,

Project menu -> Properties -> Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> NVCC Compiler

append `-rdc=true` to either the string of "Command" or the string of "Command line pattern"

You may also need to append this option to the NVCC linker command.

Comment: Thanks..it built properly but now it linker is showing error..undefined reference to `__cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_39_tmpxft_000023b3_00000000_6_Kernel_cpp1_ii_51e07f2f'. I added -lcudadevrt to nvcc linker as per nvidia manual.